# Kubernetes FailedScheduling using nodeSelector

Tags: linux, windows, kubernetes, rancher, flannel

I have set an On-Prem Kubernetes cluster using Rancher, with 3 Centos nodes and 1 Windows node.
I wanted to set a Deployment that will never run over the Windows node, so I set in the Deployment spec.template.spec.nodeSelector: kubernetes.io/os: linux

It seems to run but the deployment gets stuck in Pending, with this error:

> Warning  FailedScheduling    default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are
> available: 1 node(s) didn't match node selector, 3 node(s) had taint
> {cattle.io/os: linux}, that the pod didn't tolerate.

Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheduler is not able to schedule the pod on linux nodes because those nodes have got taints. So you need to add [tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) in the pod spec of the deployment.

```
  tolerations:
  - key: "cattle.io/os"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "linux"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Also add a specific taint to the windows nodes so that only specific pods with specific tolerations can only be scheduled onto the windows nodes

```
kubectl taint nodes windowsnode cattle.io/os=windows:NoSchedule
```

Comment: YAY Thanks, it worked! Just fix the operator: "Equals" to operator: "Equal"

Comment: OK wait, I can still see that when I scale up the deployment, it still tries to apply one of the pods to the Windows node...

Comment: OK Fixed by adding a taint that was missing, to the windows node using:
kubectl taint nodes windows cattle.io/os=windows:NoSchedule

Comment: @tal47 Added that to my answer